# How do I set a search path for non existing php files in current directory?

Tags: php, file, path, include, require

Title is pretty much self explanatory...

I need to do the same thing in php as dos do with the command :

```
path %windir%/whateverdirectory
```

so iow

```
<?php

//if file is NOT exists on the current directory look for other default directory

require_once('thisFileIsNotInCurrentDirectoryButStillFoundable.php');

?>
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the "include_path" configuration option, which ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)):

> Specifies a list of directories where the [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) and [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) functions look for files. The format is like the system's PATH environment variable: a list of directories separated with a colon in Unix or semicolon in Windows.
>
> PHP considers each entry in the include path separately when looking for files to include. It will check the first path, and if it doesn't find it, check the next path, until it either locates the included file or returns with a [warning](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) or an [error](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). You may modify or set your include path at runtime using [set_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).